# How to regroup records with different values in one SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

Let's say I have the following table :

```
Name - Country - Age
--------------------
Toto - Switzerland - 10
Titi - France - 12
Tata - Italy - 21
Tutu - England - 13
Tete - Italy - 14
```

I want to create a `sql query` as simple as possible to regroup people living in defined grouped countries like :

Group A = Switzerland + Italy
Group B = France + England

I don't know how to create a `group` withn my `records` with a `column` that could have multiple different `values` in the same group...

Could somebody help me with this ?

More information : `SQL Server 2008 database`.

Comment: u can make groups but u cannot make according to name or age  as they are different values but u can make according to something like avg(age) or concat(names), max(age0 etc...

Comment: For what database?  And what have you tried?

Comment: For the example purpose, let's say I could define my group in my sql query !

Comment: Actually I know the group by clause, but I don't know at all how to regroup with a sort of group by, but in which the grouped columns could have different values...

Comment: u can concat them as one value that's possible with comma, space etc. is that what u want?

Comment: Let's take another example. If I do a "SELECT * FROM .... GROUP BY Country", i'll get records grouped by country. That's the first step, and now, I want to regroup by country, but I want my groups to have not a single country, but many countries (defined by me in my sql)...

Comment: I will say you are playing with fire. You have Group by and there is no aggregation function on cols not included in group by clause. Behavior of this query will vary with DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
             Select * from (select *,case when Country ='Switzerland' then 'A'
                         when Country ='Italy' then 'A'  
                         when Country ='France' then 'B'  
                         when Country ='England' then 'B'  
                    else 'C' end) classification from table1)
         order by classification
```

This will group the ppl as per your criteria. If this grouping is static you can have seprate table and use inner join. That will make query more readable

Comment: Also very interesting, I think you got what I wanted as well ! I'll give it a try ! Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(Name), GroupA, GroupB FROM
   (`SELECT Name, Country, Age,
   Country='Switzerland' OR Country='Italy' As GroupA,
   Country='France' OR Country='England' As GroupB)
Group By GroupA, GroupB
```

Comment: Very interesting, I think you got what I wanted ! I'll give it a try ! Thanks for your answer !

Comment: To be honest, @ejb_guy suggested something I'm not familiar with. I don't know if it's standard, but may be worth checking on your implementation.

Comment: Well it should not even execute on any db i have worked with (worked with abt 5 dbs till date)

Comment: @ejb_guy If your comment was meant to me - the statement is pretty trivial, and, at any rate, was tested on sqlServer

Comment: @JNF tx for clarification. I will like to understand what happening here. *Country='Switzerland' OR Country='Italy' As GroupA* what this line is supposed to do.

Comment: @ejb_guy return true (or 1) iff it belongs to the group. Then you have group A with true in GroupA column, group B with true in GroupB col. etc.